# Struct name from variable in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, variables, struct, matlab-struct

I have created a structure containing a few different fields. The fields contain data from a number of different subjects/participants.

At the beginning of the script I prompt the user to enter the "Subject number" like so:

```
 prompt='Enter the subject number in the format SUB_n: ';
 SUB=input(prompt,'s');
```

Example SUB_34 for the 34th subject.

I want to then name my structure such that it contains this string... i.e. I want the name of my structure to be `SUB_34`, e.g. SUB_34.field1. But I don't know how to do this.

I know that you can assign strings to a specific field name for example for structure `S` if I want `field1` to be called `z` then

```
S=struct;
field1='z';
S.(field1);
```

works but it does not work for the structure name.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: one option would be using `eval` although is not a good programming practice:   `eval([SUB ' = struct'])`  will create a struct variable whose name is the content of SUB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than creating structures named `SUB_34` I would *strongly* recommend just using an array of structures instead and having the user simply input the subject *number*.

```
number = input('Subject Number')
S(number) = data_struct
```

Then you could simply find it again using:

```
subject = S(number);
```

If you really insist on it, you *could* use the method proposed in the comment by @Sembei using `eval` to get the struct. You really [*should not* do this though](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

```
S = eval([SUB, ';']);
```

Or to set the structure

```
eval([SUB, ' = mydata;']);
```

One (of many) reasons *not* to do this is that I *could* enter the following at your prompt:

```
>> prompt = 'Enter the subject number in the format SUB_n: ';
>> SUB = input(prompt, 's');
>> eval([SUB, ' = mydata;']);
```

And I enter:

```
clear all; SUB_34
```

This would have the unforeseen consequence that it would remove *all* of your data since `eval` evaluates the input string as a command. Using `eval` on user input assumes that the user is never going to ever write something malformed or malicious, accidentally or otherwise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117732/discussion-on-answer-by-suever-struct-name-from-variable-in-matlab).